# Getting Gloss to work in Haskell

Tags: haskell, graphics

I can't seem to get gloss working on haskell. I already have gloss-1.8.0.1 installed via "cabal install gloss". This is my circle.hs file.

```
import Graphics.Gloss
main = display (InWindow "Nice Window" (200, 200) (10, 10)) white (Circle 80)
```

From my understanding, when I open this file via ghci. A window will pop up with the name "Nice Window" and it will have my circle nicely drawn out for me.

However, when I open it. here's the output.

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             C:\Users\... Path here, interpreted
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main>
```

Even when I try to draw directly in ghci

```
import Graphics.Gloss
picture = circle 80
```

would return

```
<interactive>:3:9 parse error on input '='
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've defined a `main`, but didn't tell ghci that you wanted to execute it. To do that, simply type `main`. In case your program needs arguments, you can use `:main arg1 arg2` to pass `arg1` and `arg2` as if they were on the command-line.

When defining things inside ghci, you must use `let`. So to define `picture`, you would write

```
let picture = circle 80
```

As with the previous thing, this defines `picture` but doesn't do anything with it; if you want something to happen, you'll have to say exactly what code to execute.

Answer (score 2):

Use `runhaskell` instead of `ghci`.